# Plist writeToFile overwrites the entire plist

Tags: ios

I have been successfully using a Plist to read and write data in my iPhone app. The Plist consists of dictionaries in arrays. When I want to append a dictionary I use the writeToFile method. This works well but it overWrites the entire Plist. Is there way to add to a dictionary without having to read the whole Plist and then right the whole Plist back again ??

Answer (score 1):

Pete, if I understand your question correctly, you should do the following:

Load your plist file in an `NSMutableArray`. Then, when you want to add another dictionary, instead of saving it directly (it will of course overwrite...), you just add this dictionary to your existing `NSMutableArray` and then you save it.

```
NSMutableArray *arrayLoaded = <load here your plist>
NSDictionary *dictionaryToAdd = <create your dictionary>

[arrayLoaded addObject:dictionaryToAdd];
[arrayLoaded writeToFile:filePath];
```

Comment: But when you save the arrayLoaded with writeToFile will it then rewrite the entire Plist ?  My Plist contains quite a few NSData objects and my app slows down if I want to change just a small string or something in a dictionary within the Plist. Unfortunately I'm away from my mac but I will try you answer later on.

Comment: Yes, it rewrites the plist file. I think it will keep the NSData objects. Otherwise, you can try to store these data separated, in two different files.

Comment: I like the 2 Plist idea - I'll give it go. Thanks.